# script to fill formula on googledocs

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

Well, I've created a script to check if a column contains a formula, and if it does not contain it, it inserts it. I'm doing this because every time I fill out a form, the formula that was before in the cell disappears. Soon, the script will run every hour, check if the formula has been deleted and, if so, it inserts it again. However, it is not working, although it does not show any errors, the formula does not appear in the column as it should. 
The script is this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 0;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();  //Get all values except the header rows


  for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){ 
  var prazo = dataRange[i][8];
    if (prazo = '') {
      prazo = '=IF(COUNTA(E4)=0;"";E4-TODAY())'; 

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is always supposed to contain a formula, perhaps it is easiest to just force this to be the case (instead of testing.)

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range  = sheet.getRange("I2:I");
  range.setValue('=IF(COUNTA(E4)=0;"";E4-TODAY())');
}
```